# play mp4 video in starling air mobile app

Tags: android, actionscript-3, video, air, starling-framework

i am building an adobe air mobile app that records video on an android device using cameraUI. this is returning a mp4 video that i need to playback on a play back screen. in the adobe docs it says that fl.video only deals with flv s. and stage video is not compatible with starling as it displays on the bottom layer and wont be visable. i had it working using a class i found in a blog post some time ago but the results were very inconsistent on different devices and it was before i implemented starling and feathers.
has any one got around this or have any advice for me. help would be greatly appreciated. please comment if you want clarification on any thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully soon there will be an Android version of the MediaPlayer ANE from distriqt.com that will allow you to play mp4 files with the native video player.

Currently this is only available on iOS but I was told the Android version would be available in May 2014.

If you're interested perhaps email distriqt to get an update.